# PhoneGap focus() glitch

Tags: javascript, css, ios, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap application for iOS. I have a feature that auto focuses on the main field when the user navigates to a page. What happens is:

1. field.focus() is called
2. keyboard pops up
3. viewport appears to shift (see image)
4. few milliseconds later (a noticeable duration) it looks like it's supposed too.

I'm guessing it's related to the viewport provided by PhoneGap, a rendering glitch. Is there a CSS or JS fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Probably function `MBP.scaleFix` from BP helps you:
https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/blob/master/js/helper.js
Could you try?

Comment: MBP offered no improvements. Though I will play around with MBP.fastButton later on, looks like a handy function.